# Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found in laravel 5.2 ,how to do call recording using Twilio of incoming and out going calls

Tags: laravel-5, twilio

This is My code

```
 $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

 $call = $client->calls->create(
        "+9xxxxxxxxxx9",
        array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", "record" 
      => true)
    );
```

how to do call recording using Twilio of incoming and out going calls?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you updated `composer.json` to include the Twilio library?

If not, run the following command line:

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

This should then update composer and download the SDK files. See if this fixes your issue.

[Or follow the setup instructions here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php).

---

If you have already added twilio to the `composer.json` file, try running:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

And then

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Am trying  `composer require twilio/sdk` command, but i got an error, ** installation failed reverting ./composer.json to its original content ** on cmd.Then what to do?

Comment: Sounds like you have a error in your composer.json file. Was there a more specific error message? And can you share the composer.json file?

Comment: ` "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
  "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*", 
        "aloha/twilio": "^3.0"
    } `

Comment: You've already for a twilio library added to composer. Have you tried runnin `composer update --no-scripts`?

Comment: `composer require twilio/sdk is working ` thank you :)